# Cisco Router: Disable RIPng Process?

Tags: cisco

I have started too many RIPng processes. I want to disable a few. I start them via

```
ipv6 rip NAME enable
```

I tried:

```
ipv6 rip NAME disable
no ipv6 rip NAME enable
```

No idea, I didn't find anything on Google...

Thanks!

Comment: Try "no ipv6 rip NAME"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `no ipv6 rip NAME`. To negate a command in Cisco IOS the command is usually preceded by `no`.